# Wordpress shortcode is returning changed html

Tags: html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a WordPress shortcode function that for debug proposes i reduce it to only these 2 lines

```
$detail='<div class="property_design_intext_details"><p style="text-align: right;"><div id="add_favorites" class="isnotfavorite" data-postid="132">add to favorites</div></p></div>';
return $detail;
```

The problem appears on front end where wordpress is displaying other code. More exactly (taken from view source)

```
   <div class="property_design_intext_details"><p style="text-align: right;"><div id="add_favorites" class="isnotfavorite" data-postid="132">add to favorites</div></div>
```

The closing `</p>` tag is missing.

Any idea about why this is happening and how i can prevent it.

Comment: try not adding div element inside p element, try span inside of p instead of div. This should not actually affect shortcode output but still..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser fixes your broken HTML.

Do not put `<div>` inside `<p>`.

It is impossible to place a `<div>` element inside a `<p>` in the DOM because the opening `<div>` tag will automatically close the `<p>` element.

Comment: Ups - i think you got it - once i changed the div inside the p with a span everything works. Thanks for taking the time to look over .